# Update model schema in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, schema, mongoid

I have a Ruby On Rails application in API mode and using Mongoid.
this is my model:

```
class Posts
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title        ,  type: String
  field :created_at   ,  type: Time , default: Time.now
end
```

Now after a while and having many records in Post collection, from now on I need to add a field `"body"` into  the model like this:

```
class Posts
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title        ,  type: String
  field :body         ,  type: String
  field :created_at   ,  type: Time , default: Time.now
end
```

The problem is, the application still does not understand this change yet! I'm not using builtin SQL database of Rails and there is no `"db"` folder in my app because its API mode and using Mongoid. So I can not use command `rails db:migrate`
So how can I  update a Mongoid model in a Rails app?

Also another question is how can I use it schema-less? I just define the name of model and not defining any field. And dunging adding functions, just pass the JSON object of new record and work with it as a schema-less model.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does not require anything like migration feature of ActiveRecord. At any time you can add a field to your model and start using it in the rest of your application. In existing documents the value of the field will be `nil`.

To use fields without explicitly defining them, use the dynamic fields feature of Mongoid: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-documents/#dynamic-fields